# How can we read the vm file into web content folder from spring controller

Tags: java, file, spring-mvc

I am trying to read the vm file from web content folder using spring controller, but not able to do this. I am using tomcat server with eclipse env.

I am using the following code:

```
ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
String path = context.getContextPath() + "/resources/text.vm";
VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
VelocityContext ctxt = new VelocityContext();
try {
    Template template = ve.getTemplate(path);
} catch (ResourceNotFoundException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (ParseErrorException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Is there any other way to do this thing?

Comment: Do you catch any error message?

Comment: I got the following exception :org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource '/catchyourlead/resources/test.vm'
 at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.loadResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:483). In which catchyourlead is context name in side resources is folder and test.vm is resource to be read.

Comment: Could you try `String path = context.getRealPath("/resources/text.vm");` instead?

Comment: It does not work. I did something different.  we need config the velocity resource that                                                                                          velocityEngine.setApplicationAttribute("javax.servlet.ServletContext", servletContext); 
 velocityEngine.setProperty("resource.loader", "webapp"); 
 velocityEngine.setProperty("webapp.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.tools.view.servlet.WebappLoader"); 
 velocityEngine.setProperty("webapp.resource.loader.path",

Comment: @user3218669 Any update on this. I'm facing the same issue.